# nable to uprade to ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04

Tags: 20.04, updates, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

Error updating from 20.04 to 22.04 . I have read so many threads and tried so many things. Not sure what to do next. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

This was likely caused by:

- Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
  Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
  package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
  try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

main log file

```
2023-08-25 18:36:02,838 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.focal', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2023-08-25 18:36:02,838 INFO uname information: 'Linux johan-XPS-15-7590 5.15.0-79-generic #86~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 23:27:17 UTC 2023 x86_64'
2023-08-25 18:36:03,072 INFO apt version: '2.0.9'
2023-08-25 18:36:03,072 INFO python version: '3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0]'
2023-08-25 18:36:03,076 INFO release-upgrader version '22.04.17' started
2023-08-25 18:36:03,083 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2023-08-25 18:36:03,114 INFO screen could not be run
2023-08-25 18:36:03,140 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2023-08-25 18:36:03,171 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2023-08-25 18:36:03,198 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2023-08-25 18:36:11,250 DEBUG lsb-release: 'focal'
2023-08-25 18:36:11,251 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2023-08-25 18:36:11,251 DEBUG openCache()
2023-08-25 18:36:11,251 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2023-08-25 18:36:11,251 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2023-08-25 18:36:11,834 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-78 with 
2023-08-25 18:36:11,835 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-79 with 5.15.0-78
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89030
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG depends: 'apt (>= 2.0.4)'
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG checking: '[('apt', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2023-08-25 18:36:11,976 DEBUG depends: 'libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.0.4)'
2023-08-25 18:36:11,977 DEBUG checking: '[('libapt-pkg6.0', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2023-08-25 18:36:11,978 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2023-08-25 18:36:12,958 DEBUG openCache()
2023-08-25 18:36:13,443 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-78 with 
2023-08-25 18:36:13,444 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-79 with 5.15.0-78
2023-08-25 18:36:13,546 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89030
2023-08-25 18:36:13,546 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2023-08-25 18:36:13,546 DEBUG quirks: running jammyPostInitialUpdate
2023-08-25 18:36:13,546 DEBUG running Quirks.jammyPostInitialUpdate
2023-08-25 18:36:13,936 DEBUG running Quirks._test_and_fix_missing_nvidia_metapackage
2023-08-25 18:36:14,588 DEBUG package nvidia-driver-535 detected, exit.
2023-08-25 18:36:15,538 DEBUG Snap core20 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:15,772 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-38-2004 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:15,773 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-38-2004 is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:16,011 DEBUG Snap gtk-common-themes is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:16,443 DEBUG Snap snap-store is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:17,044 DEBUG Snap bare is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:17,045 DEBUG Snap bare is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:17,338 DEBUG Snap canonical-livepatch is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:17,339 DEBUG Snap canonical-livepatch is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:17,580 DEBUG Snap code is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:17,581 DEBUG Snap code is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:17,783 DEBUG Snap core is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:17,784 DEBUG Snap core is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:18,048 DEBUG Snap core18 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:18,048 DEBUG Snap core18 is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:18,301 DEBUG Snap core22 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:18,302 DEBUG Snap core22 is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:18,641 DEBUG Snap cups is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:18,642 DEBUG Snap cups is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:18,864 DEBUG Snap dbeaver-ce is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:18,865 DEBUG Snap dbeaver-ce is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:19,068 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:19,068 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-28-1804 is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:19,240 DEBUG Snap gnome-42-2204 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:19,240 DEBUG Snap gnome-42-2204 is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:19,465 DEBUG Snap heroku is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:19,465 DEBUG Snap heroku is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:19,672 DEBUG Snap iptvnator is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:19,673 DEBUG Snap iptvnator is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:19,938 DEBUG Snap node is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:19,939 DEBUG Snap node is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:20,250 DEBUG Snap onlyoffice-desktopeditors is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:20,250 DEBUG Snap onlyoffice-desktopeditors is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:20,521 DEBUG Snap postman is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:20,522 DEBUG Snap postman is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:21,012 DEBUG Snap pycharm-community is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:21,012 DEBUG Snap pycharm-community is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:21,374 DEBUG Snap snapd is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:21,374 DEBUG Snap snapd is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:21,670 DEBUG Snap spotify is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:21,670 DEBUG Snap spotify is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:21,905 DEBUG Snap tvheadend is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:21,906 DEBUG Snap tvheadend is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:22,158 DEBUG Snap vlc is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:22,159 DEBUG Snap vlc is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:22,405 DEBUG Snap zoom-client is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:22,406 DEBUG Snap zoom-client is not tracking the release channel
2023-08-25 18:36:22,705 DEBUG Snap gnome-3-34-1804 is installed
2023-08-25 18:36:24,677 DEBUG MetaPkgs: ubuntu-desktop
2023-08-25 18:36:27,996 DEBUG Foreign: containerd.io cuda cuda-12-2 cuda-cccl-12-2 cuda-command-line-tools-12-2 cuda-compiler-12-2 cuda-cudart-12-2 cuda-cudart-dev-12-2 cuda-cuobjdump-12-2 cuda-cupti-12-2 cuda-cupti-dev-12-2 cuda-cuxxfilt-12-2 cuda-demo-suite-12-2 cuda-documentation-12-2 cuda-driver-dev-12-2 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-535 cuda-gdb-12-2 cuda-libraries-12-2 cuda-libraries-dev-12-2 cuda-nsight-12-2 cuda-nsight-compute-12-2 cuda-nsight-systems-12-2 cuda-nvcc-12-2 cuda-nvdisasm-12-2 cuda-nvml-dev-12-2 cuda-nvprof-12-2 cuda-nvprune-12-2 cuda-nvrtc-12-2 cuda-nvrtc-dev-12-2 cuda-nvtx-12-2 cuda-nvvp-12-2 cuda-opencl-12-2 cuda-opencl-dev-12-2 cuda-profiler-api-12-2 cuda-runtime-12-2 cuda-sanitizer-12-2 cuda-toolkit-12-2 cuda-toolkit-12-2-config-common cuda-toolkit-12-config-common cuda-toolkit-config-common cuda-tools-12-2 cuda-visual-tools-12-2 docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin gds-tools-12-2 libcublas-12-2 libcublas-dev-12-2 libcufft-12-2 libcufft-dev-12-2 libcufile-12-2 libcufile-dev-12-2 libcurand-12-2 libcurand-dev-12-2 libcusolver-12-2 libcusolver-dev-12-2 libcusparse-12-2 libcusparse-dev-12-2 libnpp-12-2 libnpp-dev-12-2 libnvidia-cfg1-535 libnvidia-common-535 libnvidia-compute-535 libnvidia-compute-535:i386 libnvidia-decode-535 libnvidia-decode-535:i386 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-encode-535:i386 libnvidia-extra-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libnvidia-gl-535 libnvidia-gl-535:i386 libnvjitlink-12-2 libnvjitlink-dev-12-2 libnvjpeg-12-2 libnvjpeg-dev-12-2 libxnvctrl0 nsight-compute-2023.2.0 nsight-systems-2023.2.3 nvidia-compute-utils-535 nvidia-dkms-535 nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-kernel-common-535 nvidia-kernel-source-535 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-535 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535
2023-08-25 18:36:27,996 DEBUG Obsolete: cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-12-2-local google-chrome-stable jdk-14.0.2 libicu55 libssl1.0.0 local microsoft-edge-stable pgdg-keyring protonvpn protonvpn-cli protonvpn-gui python3-proton-client python3-protonvpn-nm-lib rvm slack-desktop steam-libs-amd64 steam-libs-i386:i386 yarn
2023-08-25 18:36:27,997 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2023-08-25 18:36:28,006 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2023-08-25 18:36:28,007 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2023-08-25 18:36:28,007 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2023-08-25 18:36:28,009 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2023-08-25 18:36:28,011 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,011 DEBUG verifySourcesListEntry: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
2023-08-25 18:36:28,011 DEBUG url_downloadable: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release
2023-08-25 18:36:28,011 DEBUG s='http' n='archive.ubuntu.com' p='/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release' q='' f=''
2023-08-25 18:36:28,134 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,134 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,135 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse'
2023-08-25 18:36:28,136 DEBUG entry 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse' updated to new dist
2023-08-25 18:36:28,140 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2023-08-25 18:37:04,642 DEBUG openCache()
2023-08-25 18:37:05,102 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-78 with 
2023-08-25 18:37:05,102 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-79 with 5.15.0-78
2023-08-25 18:37:05,183 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 77967
2023-08-25 18:37:05,184 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2023-08-25 18:37:05,184 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2023-08-25 18:37:05,184 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2023-08-25 18:37:06,323 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2023-08-25 18:37:06,702 DEBUG Kernel uname: '5.15.0-79-generic' 
2023-08-25 18:37:06,710 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2023-08-25 18:37:11,593 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2023-08-25 18:37:11,594 DEBUG Removing 'gnome-cups-manager' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-08-25 18:37:11,594 DEBUG Removing 'powermanagement-interface' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-08-25 18:37:11,594 DEBUG Removing 'deskbar-applet' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-08-25 18:37:11,594 DEBUG Removing 'nautilus-cd-burner' (ubuntu-desktop PostUpgradeRemove rule)
2023-08-25 18:37:11,595 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2023-08-25 18:37:11,595 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2023-08-25 18:37:11,754 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-78 with 
2023-08-25 18:37:11,754 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-79 with 5.15.0-78
2023-08-25 18:37:11,825 INFO installing linux metapackage: linux-generic
2023-08-25 18:37:11,825 DEBUG Installing 'linux-generic' (linux metapackage may have been accidentally uninstalled)
2023-08-25 18:37:11,844 DEBUG Marking 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade
2023-08-25 18:37:11,971 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-08-25 18:37:12,201 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'
2023-08-25 18:37:12,218 DEBUG abort called
2023-08-25 18:37:12,219 DEBUG openCache()
2023-08-25 18:37:13,694 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-78 with 
2023-08-25 18:37:13,694 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-79 with 5.15.0-78
2023-08-25 18:37:13,827 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 89030
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Did you put 20.04 completely up to date before starting the upgrade?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer.

running: 
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
gives me all packages up to date.

Comment: Haha wait! is ubuntu-desktop not an ubuntu package? I got it from one of the tutorials on how to update. How did you know that? Removing it seemed to do the trick at least, thanks! xD

Comment: what do you mean "Removing the ubuntu-desktop package is a short-term workaround. It is not a long-term solution. The real solution is to identify and remove the conflicting non-Ubuntu package(s"

Isn't ubuntu-desktop the conflicting non-ubuntu package?

Comment: It means that `ubuntu-desktop` is there for a purpose. Removing it is not a viable long-term solution. And then I told you what the long-term solution really is. "My car is making a strange noise, so I removed the noisy part. I don't know what it did, but let's go for a nice long drive!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output: `2023-08-25 18:37:12,201 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'`

Looks like a human commanded apt to install a non-Ubuntu package...and that non-Ubuntu package will conflict with the upgraded dependencies of the 22.04 ubuntu-desktop package.

Review the non-Ubuntu packages that you have installed. One hopes there are very few of them.

A comment says that you have removed the removed the `ubuntu-desktop` package as a workaround. It is not a long-term solution. The real solution is to identify and remove the conflicting non-Ubuntu package(s)

Comment: I thought this part of the comment "Looks like a human commanded apt to install a non-Ubuntu package...and that non-Ubuntu package will conflict with the upgraded dependencies of the 22.04 ubuntu-desktop package."

meant that ubuntu-desktop was a non-ubuntu package?

Comment: You can answer that for yourself: `apt policy ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!